# ReactJS - Rendering a specific component based on scenario

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a specific component based on stage scenario of the page. I'm using a varriable "transitComponent" to render one of three components - a circular progress (wait) or one of two buttons once the response is received.

Any suggestions?

```
render() {
const { classes } = this.props;
if (this.state.stage==1){ transitComponent = CircularProgress};
if (this.state.stage==2){ transitComponent = CancelButton };
if (this.state.stage==3){ transitComponent = OKButton };
return (
  <div align="center">
    <br />
    <Button align="center" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick=    {this.handleOpen}>Create Profile</Button>
    <Modal aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title" aria-describedby="simple-    modal-description" open={this.state.open} onClose={this.handleClose}>
      <div style={getModalStyle()} className={classes.paper}>
        <Typography variant="title" id="modal-title" align="center">
          {this.state.message}
        </Typography>
        {transitComponent}
      </div>
    </Modal>
  </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `CircularProgress`, `CancelButton` or `OKButton` to a temporary variable `transitComponent`, depending on the current `state.stage`. That's OK, the only part you got wrong is how you render that component.

Since `transitComponent` is a component like any other, you don't render it with curly braces, but as a component, so `<transitComponent />` would be the proper way.

One more thing: Since React naming convention requires you to name components capitalized, you should name it `TransitComponent` and render it as `<TransitComponent />`.

And don't forget to declare `TransitComponent` with a `let` statement!

Updated code example:

```
render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;
  let TransitComponent;
  if (this.state.stage==1){ TransitComponent = CircularProgress};
  if (this.state.stage==2){ TransitComponent = CancelButton };
  if (this.state.stage==3){ TransitComponent = OKButton };
  return (
    <div align="center">
      <br />
      <Button align="center" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleOpen}>Create Profile</Button>
      <Modal aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title" aria-describedby="simple-modal-description" open={this.state.open} onClose={this.handleClose}>
        <div style={getModalStyle()} className={classes.paper}>
          <Typography variant="title" id="modal-title" align="center">
            {this.state.message}
          </Typography>
          <TransitComponent />
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much Patrick. This works. I also found a method to do the following as well:

{this.state.stage===1 && <CircularProgress />}
{this.state.stage===2 && <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleClose}>OK</Button>}
{this.state.stage===3 && <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component={Link} to="/loginProfile" onClick={this.handleClose}>OK</Button>}

Comment: Sure, that's even better, more elegant